# Configure HAProxy unreachable server

Tags: apache, web, load-balancing, haproxy, high-availability

If I configure HAProxy to load-balance 3 back-end apache servers with 'check' option on, sample example below from web, and I know in advance that at least one of these servers will not be contactable (i will not know in advance which one). Will HAProxy try to send a user request to this potentially dead server before it figures out it is dead or will 'check' option ensure that no user requests go there

```
backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    server web01 1.1.1.1:9000 check
    server web02 1.1.1.2:9000 check
    server web03 1.1.1.3:9000 check
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will not send to dead apache server because haproxy cant be able to connect apache server...it will check if no response from one apache then it will send to other nodes